# Evaluating the definite integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n e^{-a x^2+bx}}{(e^{b x}-1)^2}dx.$

Tags: integration

Can anyone help me with the following integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n e^{-a x^2+bx}}{(e^{b x}-1)^2}dx. \quad(1)$$
I have tried substitution and using standard integral tables and I have also tried to put the integral in the well-known form
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n e^{x}}{(e^{x}-1)^2}dx=n!\zeta(n).\quad (2)$$
but I had not succeeded.

I would basically like to know if the integral (1) can be evaluated exactly, or if it is necessary to use a series expansion for the $e^{-ax^2}$.

Comment: Please provide more context to the question. Also, let us know what you have tried. You can consult: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/885456

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The question has been corrected.